# How to export table(s) to Excel file(s) using script (preferably using SQLDeveloper)?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I was asked to regularly export certain DB-tables (Oracle DB) to Excel sheets.
I can do this easily using SQLDeveloper (on table -> right-click -> export -> choose Excel 2003+) but this is tedious, if one needs to do this repeatedly and for many tables.

Is there a way to script this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the Cart.

The cart can have it's contents (your specific tables) exported to excel.

The cart export command is available via the sdcli program in your sqldeveloper bin folder.

I show how to do this [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/11/scheduling-exports-of-your-data-using-the-cart/)

This screenshot shows setting up the CART for CLI, but for a delimited text file, Excel is also an option

[image]

Once you save the content (xml file), and have the cart operation options saived (another xml) file, you can make the CLI call

```
sdcli cart export -cart C:\Users\jdsmith\sf_blog_cart.sdcart -config C:\Users\jdsmith\sf_blog_cart_example.xml -target C:\Users\jdsmith\export_locations_quoted_numbers_linux_line_feeds_cli.txt
```

If CSV works just as well, you can use a bash script calling SQLcl and use set sqlformat CSV, some selects, and a spool

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Will have a look.

Comment: Hi Jeff - I finally came around to look into this. In principle it looks fine BUT I have an issue (otherwise I wouldn't come back here, would I? :-) ): that export always stops after having exported 17654 records. My DB-table, however, has 981929 entries , i.e. a LOT more. Any idea, why that export always stops? There is no error message or such. At the end it simply states "Number of exported lines: 17654 - command completed". ?!?

Comment: Version of SQLDev? We have a bug in 19.2 where that's happening, but if you were using 19.1 or earlier should keep on trucking till it gets to the end.

Comment: Exactly - I'm using v19.2. Thought I update (from 19.0) before trying. Seems I now have a hole in my knee. ;-)

Comment: Hm - where do I download older versions from? There is no link to any older releases on the download page. And just replacing the version number in the URL (https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html) didn't work, either.

Comment: It seems, that links to older versions contain the build-number (like in .../sqldev-downloads-184-5458710.html). Pardon me - but this is really stupid! How am I supposed to know the build number of v19.0? I can't use v19.1 because that had another bug that blocked us... :-(

Comment: you can find 18.4 here https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-184-5458710.html -- or just do a CSV export instead of an XLSX one, and it'll work in the version you have